# Can't construct std::span<int> from temporary std::array<int>

Tags: c++, initialization, c++20, stdarray, std-span

I have the following code, which I expected to work, but it doesn't:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <span>

void foo(std::span<int>);

int main() {
    foo(std::array<int, 3>{});
}
```

clang fails to compile this:

```
<source>:7:5: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
    7 |     foo(std::array<int, 3>{});
      |     ^~~
<source>:4:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::array<int, 3>' to 'std::span<int>' for 1st argument
    4 | void foo(std::span<int>);
      |      ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I expected this to call the constructor:

> ```cpp
> template< class U, std::size_t N >
> constexpr span( const std::array<U, N>& arr ) noexcept; // (6)
> ```
>
> 4-6) Constructs a span that is a view over the array arr; the resulting span has `size() == N` and `data() == std::data(arr)`.
>
> These overloads participate in overload resolution only if `extent == std::dynamic_extent || N == extent` is `true` and the conversion from `std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(data(arr))>` to `element_type` is at most a qualification conversion.

*See [`std::span::span` on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span)*

Why are the constraints of this constructor not satisfied?

- `extent == std::dynamic_extent` for a `std::span<int>`, so the first requirement is obviously met
- `std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(data(arr))>` is `int`, which is equal to `std::span<int>::element_type = int`, so the second requirement is also met

I don't see any reason why I  wouldn't be able to call this constructor.

Comment: @Barry the edited version now fixes this problem and wouldn't produce an immediately dangling span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualification conversions can only make something more const qualified.

`decltype(data(arr))` is `const int*` for `const std::array<int, 3>&`. `const int` can not be converted to `int` via a qualification conversion.

`std::span<const int>(std::array<int, 3>{})` does work however (`const int` -> `const int`).

Comment: What is the most brief way of constructing a `std::span` from a temporary array then, or is there no one-liner?

Comment: @JanSchultke `auto& unmove(auto&& temporary) { return temporary; }` is a good way to get a non-const lvalue for a temporary. So `std::span<int>(unmove(std::array<int, 3>{}))`, or `std::span<int>([](auto&& arr)->auto&{return arr;}(std::array<int, 3>{}))` if you want that one liner. But this isn't useful outside of a very specific set of circumstances since the array immediately dies. Why not just use `auto f = std::array<int, 3>{}` (which is implicitly convertible to a span)?

Comment: It's supposed to be a demonstration of how you can avoid template parameter packs in favor of `std::span`, `std::initializer_list`, `std::array`, etc.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is also const, so you are probably looking for a const span. And maybe two overloads: `void f(std::span<const int>); inline void f(std::initializer_list<int> ilist) { f(std::span{ilist}); }`

Comment: I was looking for the opposite actually, because I want to move from the span, and a `std::initializer_list` or `std::span<const>` don't really let you do that